# How to manipulate the result of select query in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to manipulate my sql select result. I stored the variable in the database in this way `<p>asd</p>` so it will be recognized as a paragraph in my application, but I want to use it in my app's other function. 
I want to show it in this way 'asd'.

Is there any way to do it in sql? any help will be appriciated
I am using phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running [MySQL 5.1.5 or above](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/mysql-5.1-xml.html), then you could use the [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) function [`ExtractValue()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue), like this...

```
SELECT ExtractValue(col1, '/p') FROM xml_test;
```

[**Click here to see it in action at SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a4be/1)

Comment: too bad, my phpmyadmin doesnt have that function :(

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use select replace, like so:

```
select replace(replace("<p>asd</p>",'<p>',''),'</p>','')
```

[See it in action: SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/13613/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [solution](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,177343,177985#msg-177985)

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fnStripTags;
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION fnStripTags( Dirty varchar(4000) )
RETURNS varchar(4000)
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
  DECLARE iStart, iEnd, iLength int;
    WHILE Locate( '<', Dirty ) > 0 And Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate( '<', Dirty )) > 0 DO
      BEGIN
        SET iStart = Locate( '<', Dirty ), iEnd = Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate('<', Dirty ));
        SET iLength = ( iEnd - iStart) + 1;
        IF iLength > 0 THEN
          BEGIN
            SET Dirty = Insert( Dirty, iStart, iLength, '');
          END;
        END IF;
      END;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN Dirty;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
SELECT fnStripTags('this <html>is <b>a test</b>, nothing more</html>');
```